# Usage of variable in Delta Merge call in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

We have a Delta merge case in our Spark + Scala code as following:

```
deltaTable.as("existing")
            .merge(dfNewData.as("new"), "new.SerialNumber = existing.SerialNumber and new.RSid = existing.RSid")
            .whenMatched()
            .update(Map("Id1" -> col("new.Id1"),... => around 20 columns
            ))
            .whenNotMatched()
            .insertAll()
            .execute()
```

To improve the performance, I want to check partition pruning (https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into)

The SerialNumber field above in the above code is filtered in chunks with Min and Max values set (with Int variables SerialMin and SerialMax). I want to use these vals in the delta merge something like

```
deltaTable.as("existing")
            .merge(dfNewData.as("new"), "existing.SerialNumber >= lit(SerialMin) and existing.SerialNumber < lit(SerialMax) and and new.SerialNumber = existing.SerialNumber and new.RSid = existing.RSid")
            .whenMatched()
            .update(Map("Id1" -> col("new.Id1"),... => around 20 columns
            ))
            .whenNotMatched()
            .insertAll()
            .execute()
```

But the above code is throwing an error saying that this is not supported. Any idea if we can somehow use variables in the delta merge call?

Comment: can you copy and paste the error message in your question as well?

Comment: Undefined function: lit. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function that is qualified as spark_catalog.default.lit.; line 1 pos 25
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: lit. This function is neither a built-in/temporary function, nor a persistent function that is qualified as spark_catalog.default.lit.; line 1 pos 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved with the below code:

```
deltaTable.as("existing")
            .merge(dfNewData.as("new"), s"existing.SerialNumber >= $SerialMin and existing.SerialNumber < $SerialMax and and new.SerialNumber = existing.SerialNumber and new.RSid = existing.RSid")
            .whenMatched()
            .update(Map("Id1" -> col("new.Id1"),... => around 20 columns
            ))
            .whenNotMatched()
            .insertAll()
            .execute()
```